# short cbuuid vs long cbuuid ble connection ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am guessing this but connection is not successful?

0000180A-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

```
- (void)scan
{

  
  NSMutableArray *serviceUUIDs = [NSMutableArray new];
  NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
  [serviceUUIDs addObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0000180A

  [_sharedManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:serviceUUIDs options:options];
  
  // callback(@[]);
}
```

Comment: Because advertisement data maybe limited in size, some device may choose to broadcast short UUID. If you are certain this is what the device is doing, you can try `[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]`

Comment: because i can connect same btdevice, but another btdevice and another phone, i cannot connect

Comment: I think the one in your picture refers to this: [0x180A, (Device Information Service)](https://gist.github.com/brayden-morris-303/09a738ed9c83a7d14c82)

Comment: so how can i find the reason why some phone can connect but other cannot? should i change the serviceuuid in the method to other then 0x180a?

Comment: When you say 'cannot connect', do you mean it cannot discover? or it fails to connect?

Comment: maybe that service is collapsing with the same on the around?

Comment: cannot discover so not connecting

Comment: changing it to 0xff01 matters?

Comment: Maybe try scanning without specifying service UUID `[_sharedManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];` and once discovered, check advertisement data.

Comment: what advertisement data should i check i can only get its name when discovered perpheral if discovered with nil

Comment: If you have control over device's firmware (ie. either your company produces the hardware/firmware or you work with the manufacturer), then you can tell the firmware programmer to advertise a certain service UUID.

If you are trying to connect to a certain types of devices that you have no control over, then you have to try analyzing the advertisement data yourself and figure out a pattern.

Comment: 0x180A, (Device Information Service)

Comment: @OldFart so it is not advertising? cannot searchable?

Comment: not advertising on the DIS, exactly @febamod342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.0 can use both 16 bit and 128 bit UUID values.  16 bit UUIDs obviously take less space in the advertisement packets, but there are fewer of them.

The Bluetooth SIG assigns [16 bit UUIDs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) for well known services and to member organisations on request.  The current assigned values are [here](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf)

For example 0x1801 is the GATT profile and 0x180A is the device information service.

There is no 128-bit equivalent of a 16 bit UUID.

The list of services that a device offers and the services that it advertises are not the same.

As there is limited space in the advertisement packet, devices typically only advertise a subset of their services; the services that are most "useful".

For example, a heart rate monitor will advertise the heart rate service (0x180D) but not the battery or device info services, even though it will most likely offer these.

This is why you cannot discover peripherals when scanning for service 0x180A - The device information service is typically not advertised.

Once you connect to a device you can discover all of the services that it offers.

Comment: so which service should i choose here to connect, 1800 service advertises device name maybe it work

Comment: It depends on what type of device you are trying to discover.  If you want to discover "all" devices then you would scan for `nil`